# efficiently read major version number from a file

Tags: python, list, slice

I am writing a script that will check the major version  by reading the file

that at any line stores the version number Major.Minor.Fix

like this:

```
VERSION = 23.5.1
```

so to read this number 23 I am doing this

```
filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Makefile')
with open(filePath, 'r') as mkfh:
    for line in mkfh:
        if line.startswith('VERSION'):
            print line.replace(' ','').split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]
            break
```

is their more efficient way of getting the major version then using replace and split twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'VERSION\s*=\s*(\d+)')  # \s: space, \d: digits

with open('Makefile') as mkfh:
    for line in mkfh:
        matched = pattern.match(line)
        if matched:
            print matched.group(1)
            break
```

BTW, you don't need to use `os.path.join` if you are access the file in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't to use `replace`

```
print line.split('=')[-1].split('.')[0].strip()
```

`lstrip` would be more appropriate.

```
print line.split('=')[-1].split('.')[0].lstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do `line.split(' = ')[1].split('.')[0]`, but other than that it seems fine to me. Some people would probably use a regex solution, like `re.search(r'VERSION = (\d+)', line).group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is the goal, then for something like a makefile, you should probably process the file all in one go, rather than a line at a time:

```
import os
import re

filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Makefile')
with open(filePath, 'rb') as mkfh:
    data = mkfh.read()

pattern = '^VERSION *= *(\d+)'
search = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE).search

print(search(data).group(1))
```